# Regex which differentiates two urls which ends with same word

Tags: regex, wordpress, .htaccess

I have two URLs:

```
/register/Arkansas-Defensive-Driving-Online-Traffic-School.aspx
```

and

```
/register/Alabama_Autauga_Autauga-County-Circuit-Court-Traffic-School.aspx
```

I want to re-route these URLs differently, based upon if one ends with
`-Defensive-Driving-Online-Traffic-School.aspx`

and the other ends with `-Traffic-School.aspx` but does not contain `-Defensive-Driving-Online`.

Comment: Might be simpler to use two different regexes--one for the specific URL and one for the category.

Comment: I am using two different regexes but as it is url re-writing one rule is conflicting with other. Can you show me how we write two different regexes for this?

Comment: okay thanks, i will add. actually i am using wordpress "Redirection" plugin for rewriting so i have added this tag.

Comment: "...one rule is conflicting with other." - with the URLs given above you just need to make sure that the rules are in the correct order - the most specific should be first. What URLs are you wanting to rewrite these to?

Answer (score 1):

You need two rules, if you want to rewrite to different targets. Put the most specific regular expression in front, and the more general at the end, e.g.

```
RewriteRule -Defensive-Driving-Online-Traffic-School\.aspx$ /target1 [L]
RewriteRule -Traffic-School\.aspx$ /target2 [L]
```

If you want to exclude some condition, you might use a [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) with the second one

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-Defensive-Driving-Online
RewriteRule -Traffic-School\.aspx$ /target2 [L]
```

Although, this should not be necessary, unless `/target2` would match `-Traffic-School.aspx`.